# Get Order & Client Information in a Hook

Tags: php, whmcs

i have been working on Whmcs for a while now and i am trying to run a custom hook when Admin Accepts and order  but there are two things that i am not sure of doing

1. How Can I call Api Of Whmcs From A Hook file?
2. What i want to do is when a Admin accepts an order, A hook runs  and in that hook I am trying to get these things 
   **orderid** **(which order is accepted by the admin and against which user)** and the client information can you please guide me through the generic steps involved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1-You call internal API of whmcs within a hook file under `/includes/hooks/` folder.
And how to that is the following :
http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Internal_API

2- You need to call "AfterShoppingCartCheckout" hook to do that.
Simply, create a php file under `/includes/hooks/` folder, and within this file you can use the sample code below :

```
<?php

 function myActionHookFunctionvars($vars) {

     $orderId= $vars['OrderID'];

     //Run code to dı what you want here,
     // you can even call internal api here.   


 }

 add_hook("AfterShoppingCartCheckout",1,"myActionHookFunctionvars");

 ?>
```